# Setting the height as % of its parent with height: auto

Tags: css

[I wrote this codepen that does not work.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLOQZm)

HTML

```
<div class="a"> 
<div class="b">  variable content length  variable content length  variable content length  variable content length  variable content length  variable content length  variable content length 
  <div class="c"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a{
  height: 500px;
  width: 70px;

}

.c{
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

a is just a container
b is the content div with variable content size.

is there a way to do it? c can have whatever `position` as well. But: `.c` must be half the size of its variable parent

Comment: Your question is a little vague and I don't understand what you want to do. This is a simple html and css and whatever you want is possible to do.

Comment: So `.a` must be `500px` tall, and `.c` must be half `.b`. But how tall should `.b` be?

Comment: @Oriol `b` is variable. Soemtimes really tall, sometimes really short

Comment: @Franco i'll rewrite the question slighty. The question is: how can I make `c` half the size of its variable content sized parent.

Comment: @Toskan But what determines that variable height?

Answer (score 0):

Give a height to `b` too :

```
.b {
   height: 100%;
}
```

To set the height of an element in %, its parent must have a height property too (in px or in % (same rule in case it's %)).

If the height is dynamic, set the overflow property of the a-element to auto.

Comment: If the height is dynamic, set the overflow property of the a-element to auto.

Comment: You may wish to move your comments explaining your answer, to the answer. Current this answer has been flagged (not by me) as low quality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **working solution**. Notice I changed some of the colors for clarity, sorry about that.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrvLJv

```
.a{
  height: 500px;
  width: 70px;
  background:blue;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.b{
  width:100%;
  background:grey;
  position:relative;
}

.c{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index:99999;
}
```

Changes introduced:

**1.** Added `position:relative` to `.b` and `position:absolute` to `.c`, while positioning `.c` on the top left corner.

**2.** Added a `width` and `height` of, respectively, 100% and 50% to `.c`.

If i recall correctly, the rest is just for demonstrative purposes. Hope I understood your question and helped. By the way, try adding more content to the text, see if it works for you.